# Disappearing mobile navigation menu items on android stock browser

Tags: android, debugging, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, google-translate

The mobile navigation menu link items disappear or don't show when my website is viewed on a mobile phone. The theme is Tesseract responsive. This only seems to happen in android stock browser and only when google translate plugin is added. There is clearly a clash between the theme and google translate. I've tried to debug it but am getting cross-eyed. I really need the translation plugin to work. Any help would be appreciated. My website is at http://englishteacher.direct

Comment: I've set up a bare bone site (basic theme and google translate plugin) as an example of the problem at http://online4english.net

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is most likely due to the fact that the android web view is out dated and fragmented. Depending on the version of android and the device itself you will get tons of different problems in the android web view. For example I build hybrid mobile apps. We had to build in a third party web view in order for all of our apps to run the same on different android devices. As of now I am guessing the only way to fix this issue is to alert your users (if they are on a android device) not to use the stock android browser.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have been pulling my hair out over this one. It's kind of good to know that it's not something I can fix because android stock browser is garbage. Annoying though. I think I might try to remove the theme's mobile navigation menu altogether and replace it with a plugin menu solution. Ho Hum!

Comment: Yeah this through us (the company I work for) for a loop when the app would be completely different or not render at all on some devices. We ended up using the crosswalk web engine built into our app. Since you are just using a website though I am not sure what the best course of action is. Kind of like when you develop and then have to either make a bunch of exceptions for IE or throw an alert on the page that they can't use IE.

Comment: This is the google translate code which make the mobile nav menu items disappear. Maybe someone knows how to get around this:  <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>